# document.querySelectorAll Weird Behaviour

Tags: javascript

I have a simple HTML like below and corresponding java script code.

The issue is :

For `.clear` and `.result` buttons , two event listeners are getting attached and called 
(storeInput as well as their actual listener). Actually , `storeInput` should not be get called in this case

To debug issue , I commented out below two lines :

//document.querySelector(".clear").addEventListener('click',clear);
//document.querySelector(".result").addEventListener('click',calculate);

So there are no event listeners for `.clear` and `.result` buttons 
But still , `storeInput listener` gets called if they are clicked

Question is :

why `document.querySelectorAll(".digit")` and `document.querySelectorAll(".operator")` are adding event listeners to `.clear` and `.result` buttons as well ?

```js
function storeInput() {
  console.log('storeInput');
}

function clear() {
  console.log('clear');
}

function calculate() {
  console.log('calculate');
}

const digits = document.querySelectorAll(".digit");
digits.forEach(function() {
  this.addEventListener('click', storeInput);
});

const operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operator");
operators.forEach(function() {
  this.addEventListener('click', storeInput);
})

document.querySelector(".clear").addEventListener('click', clear);
document.querySelector(".result").addEventListener('click', calculate);
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<br/>
<input type="button" class="digit" value="0" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="1" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="2" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="3" />
<br/>
<input type="button" class="digit" value="4" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="5" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="6" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="7" />
<br/>
<input type="button" class="digit" value="8" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="9" />
<br/>
<input type="button" class="clear" value="C" />
<br/>
<input type="button" class="operator" value="+" />
<input type="button" class="operator" value="-" />
<input type="button" class="operator" value="/" />
<input type="button" class="operator" value="*" />
<br/>
<input type="button" class="result" value="=" />
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you with relevant CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `forEach`, `this` has no special meaning, so what you're really doing is attaching those handlers to `window`, since `this` defaults to `window` in loose mode. (You may have seen jQuery code using `each`; jQuery sets `this` to each element in an `each` callback, but `forEach` doesn't work that way.)

To use the element within the `forEach` callback, accept the element as a parameter and use that parameter, see `***` comments:

```js
function storeInput() {
  console.log('storeInput');
}

function clear() {
  console.log('clear');
}

function calculate() {
  console.log('calculate');
}

const digits = document.querySelectorAll(".digit");
digits.forEach(function(el) { // *** Note the parameter `el`
  el.addEventListener('click', storeInput);
// ^ note using the parameter
});

const operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operator");
operators.forEach(function(el) { // *** Note the parameter `el`
  el.addEventListener('click', storeInput);
// ^ note using the parameter
})

document.querySelector(".clear").addEventListener('click', clear);
document.querySelector(".result").addEventListener('click', calculate);
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<br/>
<input type="button" class="digit" value="0" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="1" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="2" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="3" />
<br/>
<input type="button" class="digit" value="4" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="5" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="6" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="7" />
<br/>
<input type="button" class="digit" value="8" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="9" />
<br/>
<input type="button" class="clear" value="C" />
<br/>
<input type="button" class="operator" value="+" />
<input type="button" class="operator" value="-" />
<input type="button" class="operator" value="/" />
<input type="button" class="operator" value="*" />
<br/>
<input type="button" class="result" value="=" />
```

---

Another option is to put a container around the digits, and another container around the operators, and just handle clicks on those containers, using the `target` property of the event object to see which digit or operator was clicked.

```js
function storeInput(e) {
  console.log('storeInput: ' + e.target.value);
}

function clear() {
  console.log('clear');
}

function calculate() {
  console.log('calculate');
}

document.querySelector(".digits").addEventListener('click', storeInput);

document.querySelector(".operators").addEventListener('click', storeInput);

document.querySelector(".clear").addEventListener('click', clear);

document.querySelector(".result").addEventListener('click', calculate);
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<div class="digits">
<input type="button" class="digit" value="0" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="1" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="2" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="3" />
<br/>
<input type="button" class="digit" value="4" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="5" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="6" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="7" />
<br/>
<input type="button" class="digit" value="8" />
<input type="button" class="digit" value="9" />
</div>
<input type="button" class="clear" value="C" />
<div class="operators">
<input type="button" class="operator" value="+" />
<input type="button" class="operator" value="-" />
<input type="button" class="operator" value="/" />
<input type="button" class="operator" value="*" />
</div>
<input type="button" class="result" value="=" />
```